# When is the implicit order of a sql query not the primary key

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by, undefined-behavior

Under which circumstances will a linq-to-sql query without explicit sorting return items not sorted by the primary key?

(I am aware that SQL statements do not have an implicit order, and that the correct way to get a defined order is to explicitly set it)

e.g.: 
Given a SQL Database with a table `parent`, and a table `children`:

Table Parent has the fields:

- *ID* (int, primary key, auto-value, clustered index)
- *name* (varchar)

Table Children has the fields:

- *ID* (int, primary key, auto-value, clustered index)
- *parentID* (int, foreign key with nonclustered index)
- *name* (varchar)

accessed with linq-to-sql in the following manner:

```
var parent = dc.Parent.First(p=>p.ID==123);
...
foreach (var child in parent.Children)
    Console.WriteLine(child.ID)
```

As far as I am aware, linq-to-sql simply executes a `select xy from Children Where parentID=123` in the background, but I am not sure whether there is some additional caching in between

*Under which circumstances will the child.IDs not be sorted in ascending order?*

If I want to guarantee the order, the correct way to do this is is obviously
`foreach (var child in parent.Children.OrderBy(c=>c.ID);`
I realize that without an explicit OrderBy the order is officially undefined, and one cannot rely on any implicit ordering.

However I have some code that did not use an explicit order until now, and passed all tests until recently but now occasionally fails, and I am simply curious about the cause.

Comment: "I am aware that SQL statements do not have an implicit order, and that the correct way to get a defined order is to explicitly set it" - so why are you asking a question that attempts to establish an implicit order? "... and I am simply curious about the cause." - you've already identified the cause - that you failed to specify an order when you required one.

Comment: I thought I made the intention very clear: I have already established the correct fix, but am still curious about the inner workings of sql-server and linq-to-sql.

Comment: Every day, on your way to work, you stop at a set of traffic lights, and coming the other way, waiting, are a red car, a yellow car and a lorry. This morning, they were the yellow car, the red car, and a green SUV. There could be *many* reasons why they're not in their usual order, and you're already aware that you had no right to *expect* them to be in a particular order...

Comment: Well, that sounds like a great mystery. If that ever happened to me, I'd try to ask them about it. It might be something mundane like traffic conditions, but if they have been in the exact same order for 10+ years despite all odds, there is always the chance they have a funny story to tell. My definition of fun may be different to yours though.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is probably that the selectivity of the data in the child table changed. This leads to changes in/of the statistics of the table, which would be an explanation for the order of the data suddenly changing. You simply were lucky that it happened to sort things in the order yo wanted before, but the only way to guarantee a certain order is by using an explicit ORDER BY statement.

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand. What do you mean by changes in the selectivity of the data in the child table?

Comment: I'm not really sure how else to describe it other than "the selectivity of the data". The engine uses the statistics (which contain, among others) information about the selectivity (i.e. uniqueness of values) of rows. It uses these statistics to figure out the best way to retrieve data. If the statistics info changes due to changes in the data, the order might change as a result.

I have seen it happen before, and it can change overnight, kind of like you described.